# Laravel framework using slack interactive message

Tags: php, json, laravel, slack, slack-api

laravel using integrate the slack when i create a task and applying leave & Permission in my laravel app it will receive the message in slack app for particular channel
Now i am using Laravel 5.2 and also using this composer package like(composer require maknz/slack)but i can't show the interactive message
Here the Source code

```
$settings = [
        'username'   => Auth::user()->name,
        'icon' => 'http://iosicongallery.com/img/512/slack-2014.png', 
        'link_names' => true   
      ];  
      $client = new \Maknz\Slack\Client('https://hooks.slack.com/services/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',$settings);
      $userslack = $client->attach([
          'fallback' => 'Fallback',
          'callback_id'=> 'game',
            'color' => 'danger',
            'attachment_type' => 'default',
            'fields' => [
                [
                    'title' => 'From Date',
                    'value' => $fr_date,
                    'short' => true 
                ],
                [
                    'title' => 'To Date',
                    'value' => $to_date,
                    'short' => true
                ],
                [
                    'title' => 'Reason',
                    'value' => $leave->description,
                    'short' => true
                ]
            ],
            'actions' => [
                [
                    'name' => 'leave',
                    'text' => 'Approved',
                    'style' => 'default',
                    'type' => 'button',
                    'value' => 'approve',
                    'confirm' => [
                        'title' => 'title1',
                        'text' => 'Your Leave Requested has been Approved',
                        'ok_text' => 'Yes',
                        'dismiss_text' => 'No',
                    ],
                ],
                [
                    'name' => 'leave',
                    'text' => 'Cancel',
                    'style' => 'default',
                    'type' => 'button',
                    'value' => 'cancel',
                    'confirm' => [
                        'title' => 'Title 2',
                        'text' => 'Your leave request is cancelled',
                        'ok_text' => 'No',
                        'dismiss_text' => 'No',
                    ],
                ],
            ],
      ])->send('Ofman Leave and Permission');
```

I need exactly Output Interactive message in my Slack app like this screenshots for interactive message example

https://a.slack-edge.com/dcb1/img/api/message_guidelines/Example_6.gif

Thanks in advance